# HTTP POST "/" character problem in request body -Swift

Tags: swift, http, http-post

In swift I am trying to make a HTTP Post and in the body there is a dictionary with a String value "djaskd/ffk".

When I change the "/" char its working but i need this "/". How can I use "/" char in my http body.

```
let session = URLSession.shared
var request = URLRequest(url:post_url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-81", forHTTPHeaderField:"ContentType")
request.addValue("application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
let parameters = NSMutableDictionary()
parameters.setValue("sfala/4nv", forKey:"key")
request.httpBody = try JSONSerilization.data(withJSONObject:parameters, options .prettyPrinted)
```

Thanks

Comment: Probably unrelated but worth fixing: "application/json; charset=utf-81" - there is no charset parameter on application/json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try this

```
let session = URLSession.shared
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "url")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-81", forHTTPHeaderField: "ContentType")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
let parameters = NSMutableDictionary()
parameters.setValue("sfala/4nv", forKey: "key")
let asd = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
request.httpBody = asd

print(String(data: asd, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
```

Аnd console prints

```
"key" : "sfala\/4nv"
```

Make sure you did everything right.